# font-face doesn't appear to be working in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face, opentype

I have the following lines in my CSS.

```
@font-face { font-family: Keffeesatz; src: url(/Styles/YanoneKaffeesatz-Light.otf) format("opentype") }
@font-face { font-family: KeffeesatzBold; src: url(/Styles/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.otf) format("opentype") }
```

In IE9, these show up.  In IE8, it's using the fallback font, Arial.  How do I get this to work in IE8?

Comment: Try running your font through [fontsquirrel's generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and see what it cranks out. For custom fonts to work cross-browser you need to have the font available in several formats.

Comment: Looks like fontsquireel's generator isn't working for me.  After I upload files, it still says I have no files uploaded and there are no fonts in the download that it provides.  I've tried with both FireFox 10 and IE8.  I will try with another browser tonight when I get home.

Comment: FontSquirrel's website is being really, really slow for me today. I wonder if they're having some issues. You could also take a look at some of the [google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) to see how they've done things.

Comment: @GGG: Yeah there was a bit of a server hiccup for a while, but it's back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to supply an EOT version of your font in order for older versions of IE to embed it. They won't recognize any other format, which is why you're observing the fallback to Arial.

Take your font to the [Font Squirrel `@font-face` Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and it'll prepare everything for you, including a new set of CSS `@font-face` rules to use over your existing ones.

Comment: Finally got Font Squirrel to work for me.  Love the output! Fantastic!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not recognize your .ttf (TrueType) or .otf (OpenType) font faces in CSS3, at least not yet. IE recognizes an .eot (Embeddable Open Type).

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Take a look at [here](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax)

Comment: Yes, but not ie9 compatibility modes